# Did Japanese castaways land in Spanish California?

Tags: japan, california, spanish-empire, age-of-sail, nautical

George Lensen's "The Russian Push Toward Japan" says on p. 261:

> In 1815 the transport *Pavel* under the command of Navigator's Apprentice Srednii left Okhotsk with six Japanese castaways, three of whom had been shipwrecked off the Kuril islands, the others having been swept to California and brought from there by an English merchantman.

I've not been able to verify this story anywhere else. Did Japanese sailors really reach Spanish California?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This study, [Japanese Wrecks stranded and picked up adrift in the North Pacific Ocean](https://archive.org/stream/japanesewrecksst00broorich#page/10/mode/2up) by Charles Wolcott Brooks, presented before the California Academy of Sciences in 1875, published in 1876,  lists on page 10 (among dozens of other entries covering many years) what may have been the relevant encounter in 1815 (emphasis mine):

> 11. Captain Alexander Adams, formerly pilot at Honolulu, relates that  March 24, 1815, in latitude  32° 45' N., longitude 126° 57' W., when
>       sailing  master of brig *Forrester*, Captain Piggott, and cruising off
>       Santa Barbara, California, he sighted at sunrise a Japanese junk
>       drifting at the mercy of the  winds and waves. Her rudder aud masts
>       were gone. Although blowing a  gale, he boarded the junk, and found
>       fourteen dead bodies in the hold, **the  captain, carpenter, and one
>       seaman alone surviving**; took them on board,  where by careful nursing
>       they were well in a few days. They were on a voyage from Osaka to
>       Yedo, and were 17 months out, having been dismasted in  consequence of
>       losing their rudder.

So it appears three survivors were picked up off the Santa Barbara coast in 1815.

The same page also lists a couple of other encounters you may find of interest.(Russian encounters).

An interesting map showing the related winds and currents can be seen in the early pages.You can see from the flow of these ocean currents how a ship which had lost the ability to navigate (broken rudder and/or masts) could end up either along Kamchatka, Alaska, or even the California Coast.

[image]

By the way, to actually answer the direct question, concerning this specific event,  it does not appear that they had *landed*, but were rescued from a ruined ship offshore.

Comment: At a guess that position should actually be 32° 45' N, 126° 57' W.

Comment: @SteveBird Thanks, I tried to catch the OCR errors, missed the numbers.

Comment: my, what a horrible outcome for a journey between two cities ON THE SAME ISLAND.

Comment: Yes, 17 months.

Comment: fwiw Debris from the 2011 Tōhoku earthquake and tsunami started to arrive in British Columbia about a year later.

Comment: Interesting, so debris made better time than a broken ship.

Comment: Note that the linked study also notes a few other instances of junks making it to the North American continent.  Besides a few landings in the Aleutians, there are #12 (wrecked in Oregon, crew landed safely), #13 (wrecked on Haida Gwaii/Queen Charlottes, crew fate unknown), #15 (wrecked in Washington, three crew survived), and #20 (stranded in Mexico, three crew survived).

Comment: Yes, The map shows the location of 11 other entries which made it to the North and South American coast, marked with + symbols. The question body asked for confirmation of the specific 1815 incident. I dislike answers which overwhelm the reader with excessive information not directly relevant to the question, so I have limited my answer to what I feel is within the scope of the question. (though the title might be broader than the body implies?)